# Creating a sign up and log in page using firebase

Tags: html, firebase, authentication

I am trying to create a very simple log in and sign up page using firebase but i am getting a errors whilst doing so, im very new to this and learning on my own. I want to be able to sign up a user and send that info to firebase and also log in users with a signed up user.

my errors are as shown below:
[image]

And this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Firebase Authentication</title>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.5.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.5.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.5.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="login-container">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <form id="login-form">
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" required><br><br>
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" required><br><br>
            <button type="button" onclick="login()">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="signup-container">
        <h2>Sign Up</h2>
        <form id="signup-form">
            <label for="signup-email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="signup-email" required><br><br>
            <label for="signup-password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="signup-password" required><br><br>
            <button type="button" onclick="signup()">Sign Up</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script>
        import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
        
        // Initialize Firebase
        const firebaseConfig = {
            #copied from the firebase website
          };

        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

        // Firebase login function
        function login() {
            const email = document.getElementById("email").value;
            const password = document.getElementById("password").value;

            firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .then((userCredential) => {
                    // User is signed in.
                    const user = userCredential.user;
                    console.log("Logged in as: ", user.email);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    const errorCode = error.code;
                    const errorMessage = error.message;
                    console.error("Error: ", errorCode, errorMessage);
                });
        }

        // Firebase signup function
        function signup() {
            const email = document.getElementById("signup-email").value;
            const password = document.getElementById("signup-password").value;

            firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .then((userCredential) => {
                    // User is signed up.
                    const user = userCredential.user;
                    console.log("Signed up as: ", user.email);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    const errorCode = error.code;
                    const errorMessage = error.message;
                    console.error("Error: ", errorCode, errorMessage);
                });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone explain whats going on here and where I have gone wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that you are trying to import `initializeApp` like this:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
```

Since you are already importing firebase directly from the script tags in the head of your file, there's no need to import `initializeApp`.

You are already correctly using the global firebase object to initialize the app here:

```
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
```

So you're actually not even using the `initializeApp` that you are importing, so you can just remove it.

Comment: Im still getting the other errors and now it says firebase is not defined.